# Angular from VS Code - Missing debugger info

Tags: angular, webpack, visual-studio-code, webpack-dev-server

Using VSCode and Angular 8+.

Some of my projects emit the mapped source files and sometimes my other proejcts don't. See the screenshots of two different applications in Chrome Debugger.

Is there a way to force, in debug mode, web page to deploy the maps so that I can debug the typescript files?

I serve the files with: **ng serve** and have tsconfig set sourceMaps to true

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look in your tsconfig file for the following line:

```
"sourceMap": true
```

If it is false, switch it to true. I've never seen it set to false without being manually set to that value though.

Alternatively, try

```
ng serve --source-map true
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, yah, that was the first thing I tried. Really wierd. I even copied the tsconfig from one proj to the other.

Comment: Hi Steve, yah I tried that. Strangely the CSS show with sourceMaps if I hover over them in dev tools in Chrome. Just no TS file appears. real head scratcher